# Running sheets VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have created many sheets (around 30) in a same workbook. I'm trying to program with VBA where a value will appear in the designated cell of the multiples all at one, but there is an issue "Run time error 9, Subscript out of range".

```
Sub Invoice()
     For i = 5 To 11
       With Sheets("Sheet" & i)
           .Range("J2") = "a"

       End With
      Next i

End Sub
```

As shown in the code, value "a" has to appear in cell J2 on every sheet from sheet5 to sheet11. Apparently, there is something, but I just don't know what has gone wrong?

Below, I tried testing with just 3 sheets and still it gives the same error. As you can see in the picture that the name of each sheet is spelled correctly? I tried rewriting the names, but it doesnt work as well...

[image]

Comment: It means that one of the sheet's name is not `"Sheet" & i` because you misspelled it or there is a white space at the end.  `Sheet5` and `Sheet5 ` are different names because there is a blank at the end of `Sheet5 `. See [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-worksheet/#Subscript_Out_of_Range) for further possible reasons.

Comment: Plase have a look [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-worksheet/#Using_the_Code_Name_of_a_Worksheet). Your codename is like `Sheet1`, `Sheet2` etc., and your worksheet name is `030`, `031` etc.

Comment: On a side note, please consider https://stackoverflow.com/q/218623/11683.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the picture you added to your post I guess you want to refer to the code name of the sheet and not to the worksheet name.

Please look [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-worksheet/#Using_the_Code_Name_of_a_Worksheet) at macromastery for an explanation of the difference.

```
Sub Invoice()

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For i = 5 To 11
            If wks.CodeName = "Sheet" & i Then
                wks.Range("J2") = "c"
            End If
        Next i
    Next wks

End Sub
```

As an additonal [note](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-worksheet/#Subscript_Out_of_Range) Run-time Error 9 Subscript out of Range when you use Worksheets in such cases is always caused by one of the following reason:

- The worksheet name given to Worksheets is spelled incorrectly.
- The name of the worksheet has changed.
- The worksheet was deleted.
- The index was to large e.g. You used Worksheets(5) but there are only
  four worksheets
- The wrong workbook is being used e.g.
  Workbooks(“book1.xlsx”).Worksheets(“Sheet1”) instead of
  Workbooks(“book3.xlsx”).Worksheets(“Sheet1”).

Answer (score 0):

"Run time error 9, Subscript out of range" in this context means that you were trying to access an item in a collection (WorkSheets collection) by providing a non-existent index.

The `Sheets(index)` accessor accepts 2 types of indexes:

1. A number, corresponding the order on which they appear in your workbook (1 based), or
2. a string, corresponding the exact name of the worksheet.
   So, in order to avoid error 9, make sure you provide a valid index value, either by passing in a number:

```
Private Sub Invoice()
    For i = 5 To 11
        Sheets(i).Range("J2") = "a"
    Next i
End Sub
```

or by specifying exactly the names of the worksheets you want to apply changes to.

Comment: This is a cool suggestion.  It avoids spelling errors in the sheet names.

Comment: How do you know `Sheet5` to `Sheet11` are at index positions 5 to 11?

Comment: How do you know Sheet5 to Sheet11 even exist? It seems more likely to me that they don't. I mean, at least not by these names.

Comment: Oh, I might have misunderstood your question.
I don't know that for sure, this is exactly why I bothered to specify what the integer indexing is based on.

Comment: @Chris Neilsen I uploaded a picture of the sheets above. As you can the name of Sheet 5 is "Sheet5", Sheet 6 is "Sheet6"...and so on. I'm using the index to refer to each individual sheet.;;;

Comment: @Mrblackey I uploaded the picture I'm talking about... The sheets are created and the names are specified clearly. I tested out with just 3 sheets from 5 to 7, but it's still showing the same despite the sheets are there in the excel....